# Why is PyUSB not working on Windows 10 despite the proper dependency being installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pyusb

I am using Python 3.8.

I have found PyUSB is suggested as the way to go; however, I have tried it but it doesn't find a backend. The included backends are for libusb0.1, libusb1.0, and OpenUSB.

libusb0.1 is legacy.

libusb1.0 is current; however, installing it through pip does not make PyUSB work (it still doesn't find a backend).

OpenUSB is a fork of libusb1.0 that focuses on multithreading support but does not have a windows version.

As an answer I would accept a way to get PyUSB working with libusb1.0; or a different python library that works on windows. The minimum functionality needed is enumeration and iteration of devices, get a specific device by ID, get device information (specifically ID from the enumerated list), browse and copy to/from the device's filesystem.

PyUSB, with or without `libusb1 (1.7.1)`

```
import usb
devices = list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))
print(devices)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\scott\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 167, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\scott\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Code\Py\Path\PhoneSync\phone_sync.py", line 12, in <module>
    devices = list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1263, in find
    raise NoBackendError('No backend available')
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
```

Answer (score 5):

What fixed the Problem for me was:

Downloading the libusb1.0.dll here: [libusb](https://libusb.info/)

For my 64Bit System goto MinGW64/dll inside the Downloaded Folder
Than Copy the libusb-1.0.dll into C:\Windows\System32